# UnicodeDecodeError in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, unicode, python-unicode

I'm trying to take a list of 2-element tuples and add them to a `SQLite` table.

The first element of the tuple is a string (encoded in `unicode utf-8`) and the second element is a `murmurhash3 hash` of that `utf-8` string.

This is the violating line:
for result in

```
self.dbc.primaryCursor.executemany("insert into Table values(?,?); 
select last_insert_rowid() as lastrowid;", ListOfTermsAndHashesTuples)
```

The error is `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128).
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: Can you put your code snippet here? Do you perform any encode/decode operations before feeding the string into SQLite?

Comment: Python thinks your string is ASCII, not UTF-8. Show how you create that string.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is very likely not in a valid UTF-8 format.
On Linux and Mac you can easily check it by putting your string into a file and running:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 <your_filename_goes_here>
```